# ADF - JSON as Sink - single line result only?

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

In the Azure Data Factory, I am sending a call to a REST API and getting a JSON in response.

My issue is the JSON is always in a single line format, which is not exactly legible.

Is there an easy way to convert the JSON files to a legible format with multiple lines? And without using external programs?

I want to see this:

```
{
    "time": "2015-04-29T07:12:20.9100000Z",
    "callingimsi": "466920403025604",
    "callingnum1": "678948008",
    "callingnum2": "567834760",
    "switch1": "China",
    "switch2": "Germany"
}
```

While I am getting this:

```
{"time":"2015-04-29T07:12:20.9100000Z","callingimsi":"466920403025604","callingnum1":"678948008","callingnum2":"567834760","switch1":"China","switch2":"Germany"}
```

I saw in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json#json-file-patterns) the "JSON Lines" format is the default for Sink, but there's nothing in there about changing it. Changing the File pattern doesn't do what I need.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to change this.

Comment: You have not mentioned why you would need this. You just need to ensure that the data is legible to the application/system reading it. A single line JSON works just fine with pretty much any system I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. As for why I would need this... Only being pedantic here and trying to learn new things about the tool.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no way to format the JSON data in azure data factory. If you want to view this data in a formatted manner, one thing you can do as follows:

- Copy the response of the API call into a JSON file using copy data activity.

[image]

- Once this is done, create a JSON dataset for this file and use the preview data option to view the data in a formatted manner.

[image]

- But as long as the response is a valid JSON format, the single line format would not be an issue as mentioned by @AnupamChand

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already knew I can preview the data to see it like that. I could probably write my own script to make the files formatted properly. It's a pity ADF can't format the files on its own, though.

Comment: @F.R., what importance does this format have in your requirement?

Comment: No importance. I'm only being pedantic here and trying to learn new things about ADF.

Comment: Understood. There might be no option to do this within ADF itself.